# mrt:iron-router-progress in Meteor 0.9.1.1

Tags: css, meteor, iron-router

at first I have to confess that I'm a raw recruit in Meteor. Yesterday I added mrt:iron-router-progress to my meteor project because I wanted to simply add a background picture to myApp. But my Problem is that it doesn't yield into this iron-router-progress-div-Tag, but under it, so the background is not visible.

```
<body>
<div id="iron-router-progress" class="done" style="width: 100%;"></div>
<div class="page-header">
<section id="login">
</body>
```

I have following packages: 
 - standard-app-packages
 - meteorhacks:npm 
 - mrt:moment
 - less
 - nemo64:bootstrap
 - iron:router
 - npm-container
 - mrt:iron-router-progress
 - coffeescript
 - blaze
 - meteorhacks:fast-render

layout.html looks like:

```
<template name="layout">
    {{> yield region="navbar"}}
    {{> yield}}
    {{> yield region="footer"}}
</template>
```

router.js looks like:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    notFoundTemplate : 'notFound'
});

IronRouterProgress.configure({ })


Router.map( function(){
    this.route('user_verification',
        {path:'/',
        progress: {enabled: true}
            })
})
```

I define #iron-router-progress in style.css.

Comment: Hi, can you explain a bit more... because iron router progress only installed and it works. I don't have any problem with it.

Comment: Hi Walter, I don't know what else might be relevant for you... I use furthermore a bought Template which delivers me a lot of css, js and html files.

Comment: You can to use the console of chrome, here you can see, how to works iron router progress. For example, there are two status...            <div id="iron-router-progress" class="spinner" style="width: 0%;"></div>                                                                     <div id="iron-router-progress" class="spinner loading done" style="width: 100%;"></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must to install Iron Router Progress, the following way fot Meteor 0.91 or later, when you install this package just it works.

```
$ meteor add mrt:iron-router-progress
```

you don't must to put it in your code html

```
<div id="iron-router-progress" class="done" style="width: 100%;"></div>
```

Iron router progress has two status

```
<div id="iron-router-progress" class="spinner" style="width: 0%;"></div> 

<div id="iron-router-progress" class="spinner loading done" style="width: 100%;"></div>
```

if you have some problem, you must to check if you have another class spinner, loading or done that replaces something of iron router progress

Comment: Thanks, but I already installed it on this way; firebird shows me this div-tag, so I thought my code shall get in there, because iron-router-progress created it...

Comment: That spinner class works like it should, at the beginning it loads and then it shows class"spinner"... maybe the reason for that is, that I before that, installed "mrt add iron-router-progress" and then deleted it again, because it produced a lot of errors

Comment: maybe, when I installed update Meteor 0.91, I decided to create one new project, I prefered to prevent errors..

Comment: Yeah, that's true, switching through all the packages and updates, left quite a mess in my library... Thank u :)